# Why does Jacoco report show different coverages on consecutive test runs?

Tags: code-coverage, junit5, quarkus, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

I just added JaCoCo code coverage with `jacoco-maven-plugin` to a Quarkus application using `quarkus-junit5` and `maven-surefire-plugin` for unit testing.

JaCoco reports are there when I run `mvn clean verify` but I noticed that when I run them again **I get another coverage**. Most of the time the coverage report **doesn't include lines which are definetly covered by the unit tests**.

I know that the line coverage actually is at **84%**. IntelliJ IDEA coverage runner shows this one and also JaCoCo runner one time managed to show that one.

But most of the time JaCoCo report shows a much lower line coverage at **20%** or **30%**.

I am running JaCoCo in instrumentation offline mode as on-the-fly mode interfered with Quarkus.

This is my set up:

JaCoCo Agent dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
  <classifier>runtime</classifier>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

JaCoCo plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>instrument</goal>
                <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Surefire plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <jacoco-agent.destfile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
            <hibernate.search.backend.directory.type>local-heap</hibernate.search.backend.directory.type>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In case you need to know more, the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <project
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
        https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.7</jacoco.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.exparity</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-date</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-container-image-docker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-flyway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-micrometer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-mapper-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-backend-lucene</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
            <classifier>runtime</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>instrument</goal>
                            <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
                <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-index</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jandex</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parameters>true</parameters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <jacoco-agent.destfile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                        <hibernate.search.backend.directory.type>local-heap</hibernate.search.backend.directory.type>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I would appreciate if someone has an idea what is the reason for this behaviour and could help me.

In case you advise me to use the `quarkus-jacoco` extension. I tried this one by removing `jacoco-maven-plugin` and adding the `quarkus-jacoco` extension, but then I run into another problem after executing `mvn clean verify`:

```
Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException:
Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step io.quarkus.jacoco.deployment.JacocoProcessor#transformerBuildItem threw an exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/quarkus/deployment/builditem/BytecodeTransformerBuildItem$Builder
        at io.quarkus.jacoco.deployment.JacocoProcessor.transformerBuildItem(JacocoProcessor.java:71)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:972)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.quarkus.deployment.builditem.BytecodeTransformerBuildItem$Builder
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:412)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:365)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: Have you found solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason (and it's really impossible to tell without going through your entire code and its tests) is that a good chunk of your code isn't covered by tests consistently.

For example if half your code is only exercised by your tests if run between midnight and 1 in the morning, and the other half is run always, jacoco will report 100% coverage at half past midnight but only 50% at 4 in the afternoon.

That's a contrived example, but something like that is probably happening and is common if the execution path of your code depends on external factors you're not mocking away in your tests.

To give a prime example from my own distant past, one vital code path of a new module I wrote as a junior would cause a crash if and only if a specific database table was empty. That specific table had never been empty in either development, test, acceptance, or production databases in years so the problem was never noticed in testing and the person doing the code review had missed it as well as the idea of that table being empty never occurred to him. Of course the deployment to production of that module just so happened to coincide with a data conversion that caused that table to be empty for the first time in a decade, causing the module to crash immediately when powered up. Had it been powered up 10 minutes later (after the first run of the batch job that filled that table, mine only read from it) the bug would never have been noticed but it hit hard. Luckily the fix was easy and a patch went out within the hour. A unit test that mocks the relevant table and runs with different simulated loads in it could have found that bug reliably during run after run, but this was over 20 years ago on a mainframe system where such things didn't exist.

Comment: Hello, that also was my first assumption. But then I took a test case and changed a function in a java class, so that this test case always fails.
Because the test case fails on every test run, I know that the function in the java class must be covered. Yet JaCoCo mostly says the class has 0 lines covered.

Comment: Actually that java class builds all the search results, so a big part of the tests (all the filter tests) walk through that java class. Yet JaCoCo mostly says the class has 0 lines covered.